# Updating domain values of multiline graph after line drag event

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js, data-visualization

I am developing a simple multi-line graph with dual time axes and zooming/dragging features. Please take a look at my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dalapati/88bsax53/8/).

I am trying to implement the drag feature on the line graph, whereupon dragging a particular line will result in its respective axis also getting updated. Every time the drag is applied to the graph, I am trying to update the domain values of its respective axis, and redraw both the axis and the line graph.

Here is the logic that I implemented to update the domain values (referenced from a [D3 Example](http://bl.ocks.org/stepheneb/1182434)):

```
 var mousePoint = d3.mouse(this);
     x1 = x1Scale.domain()[0],
     x2 = x1Scale.domain()[1],
 console.log("x1 = "+x1+", x2 = " +x2);
     xextent = x1 - x2;
     x1 += mousePoint[0];
     x2 += mousePoint[0]; 
 var newDomain = [x1, x2];
     x1Scale.domain(newDomain);
```

When I implement this logic, I get a NaN error. Is this the correct way to update the domain values after the drag? If so, how do I solve the NaN error and achieve the desired functionality?

Answer (score 1):

It is important to convert numbers into date objects, there was a typo in your code (data1[0].time instead of data1[0].date). Also you shouldn't multiply by 1000, since your data was already in milliseconds.
In your drag code, it is also important to convert your date objects back to numbers, in order that += will work on them. Of course you also need to convert them back to date when setting the domain again.

```
function draggedData1(d) {
    console.log("dragging of data1 going on!!")

    var mousePoint = d3.mouse(this);
    var x1 = x1Scale.domain()[0].valueOf(); //date to number
    var x2 = x1Scale.domain()[1].valueOf();
    var xextent = x1 - x2;

    x1 += mousePoint[0];
    x2 += mousePoint[0];
    var newDomain = [new Date(x1), new Date(x2)]; //number back to date
    x1Scale.domain(newDomain);
    redraw();
    zoomBottom.x(x1Scale);
    zoom.x(x2Scale);
}
```

I've created a fiddle with the full code and fixes here:
http://jsfiddle.net/pb3cod6q/2/